# D3 position tooltip at smaller screen sizes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stackBlitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tootltip?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

I have a bar chart with tooltips when you hover over the bars.

The tooltips are positioned above the bars but at small screen sizes I would like to position the tooltip in middle of the window.

I can capture when the screen is small and and I also have the width of the tooltip and so the half the width which I think I'll need to position it. I just stuck how to use this in the style attribute.

```
if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
    const toolTipWidth = d3.select('.chart-tooltip').style('width');
    const halfToolTipWidth = Number(toolTipWidth)/2;

    d3.select('.chart-tooltip')
        .style("left", 50 + "%") <- I need to minus the half width here
        .style("top", 0 + "px")
        .html(html)
}else{
    d3.select('.chart-tooltip')
        .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 30 + "px")
        .style("top", 0 + "px")
        .html(html)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the CSS3 [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
You can use it to write values like `calc(50% - 10px)` (operators must be surrounded by whitespaces).

This, plus a fix on the `halfToolTipWidth` computation that gave NaN and you're done:

Edit: `toolTipWidth` also fixed.

```
let tooltip = d3.select('.chart-tooltip');

if (window.innerWidth < 500) {

  const toolTipWidth = tooltip.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const halfToolTipWidth = 40;

  tooltip
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("left", "calc(50% - " + halfToolTipWidth +"px)")
    .style("top", 0 + "px")
    .html(html)
} else {
  tooltip
    .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 30 + "px")
    .style("top", 0 + "px")
    .html(html)
}
```

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tootltip-ocdngb?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts).

Comment: Zim, the updated Stackblitz doesn't seem to work, the tooltip needs to sit in the centre of the chart

Comment: Vertically as well you mean?

Comment: I've updated the `toolTipWidth` computation which was wrong and led you to think the tooltip was not correctly centered (horizontally).
If you need to center vertically as well, you can follow the exact same steps.

Comment: Also, as a general advice, you should avoid making the same selection again and again and store it as much as possible!

Comment: How could I store the selection here ?

Comment: Is this the expected result or have I missed something?